# How sort json array result in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter, sorting

if mind, anyone can tell me how to sort by created_at on json array.
I want the newest comment on top, not on the bottom.
Here is my code :

Model (to insert and get comment data):

```
    public function add_komen($data){
            return $this->komen->insert($data);
    }

    public function get_komen($id){
            return $this->komen->where('id_user', $id)->get()->getResultArray();
        
 }
```

Controller (get data & get result using array for views):

```
public function do_add_komentar(){
        $data['nama_komentar'] = $this->request->getPost('nama');
        $data['isi_komentar'] = $this->request->getPost('komentar');
        $data['id_user'] = $_SESSION['id_user'];

        $update = $this->UndanganModel->add_komen($data);
        if($update){
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 'sukses','nama' => \esc($data['nama_komentar']),'komentar' => \esc($data['isi_komentar']) ));
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 'gagal'));
        }
}
```

Views (Form & Get Result):

```
<input id="nama" type="text" class="form-control mt-2" placeholder="Nama Anda" required>
<textarea id="komentar" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" placeholder="Pesan anda.." rows="3" required></textarea>
<button id="submitKomen" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" >Kirim</button>

<div class="layout-komen">              
                <?php  foreach($komen as $key => $data) { ?>
                <div class="komen" >
                    <div class="col-12 komen-nama">
                        <?= \esc($data['nama_komentar']); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 komen-isi">
                        <?= \esc($data['isi_komentar']); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: show the model code to get data

Comment: @VirenderKumar added, i've edited the post, thank you, im forgot to show get result model

Comment: check my answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no need to sort json array. This can be achieved simply by sorting for created_at in your model function for get result. I am assuming that created_at is column name in your table. if not then replace created_at with the column name. See code here

```
 public function get_komen($id){

   return $this->komen->where('id_user', $id)->orderBy("created_at", "desc")->get()->getResultArray();
        
 }
```

check and reply